# Multi-column index order for queries with ORDER BY

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, sql-order-by

How should I order my multi-column index for the following query?

```
SELECT * 
FROM example_table 
WHERE a=3 AND b=4 
  AND c=5 ORDER BY d, e;
```

I assume I would want to create an index with a, b, c, d, e order:

```
CREATE INDEX example_index 
    ON example_table (a, b, c, d, e);
```

But should I instead put the order by columns first in the index?

```
CREATE INDEX example_index 
    ON example_table (d, e, a, b, c);
```

Comment: I hope [ORDER BY Optimization](https://www.google.com.ph/?gws_rd=cr&ei=b7NMUqSEN-i4iQedhYDQBg#q=index+order+by+mysql) helps.

Comment: Try thinking about it with just two columns - say peoples first and second names (assuming everyone has two names). I'm going to give you a list of all of their names sorted by their second name and then by the first name, and ask you to find me all of the people called `John` and sort your output based on their surnames. Then I'll give you the same task to do but give you a list that's sorted by first names first, and then by surname. Which of those two lists do you think you can more easily use?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I know the columns I want to compare. My question is just whether the `ORDER BY` columns should come before or after the `WHERE` columns in the index column list.

Comment: If I've given you my first list (sorted surname first then first name) and ask you to find all of the people with the first name `John`, does this list help you at all? You have to look through the *entire* list to find all of the `John`s. Yes, the order you found them in was the output order you wanted, but the search took ages. Compare that to my second list (firstname then surname) - you jump straight to the `John`s and then find them all listed in surname order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the first form:

```
CREATE INDEX example_index ON example_table (a, b, c, d, e);
```

There's no point in the index first being sorted on the desired output order if the *entire* index has to be scanned to find the rows that you're interested in by your `WHERE` clause filters.